# How to join/merge multiple data frames by date and not get duplicates

Tags: r, database, dataframe

When I try to merge 3 data sets with time as ID I get duplicate values because the id is the same. I would want to get the data whiteout duplicates.

my data: https://pastebin.com/5HAhQQG5

I have tried merge by id and aggregate, but nothing seems to work and I keep getting duplicates.

```
#Dati is the data-frame where I have all the data
Dati[, "...8"]
head(Dati,3)
bi       <- Dati[,1:3] 
bi_date  <- Dati[,1]
as       <- Dati[,5:7] 
as_date  <- Dati[,5]
tr       <- Dati[,9:11] 
tr_date  <- Dati[,9]
#i split the data frame into 3 diferent ones
bi$class <- "bid" 
as$class <- "ask" 
tr$class <- "trade" 
data.frame(bi)
data.frame(as)
data.frame(tr)
#rename the columns
colnames(bi)      <-  c("time", "price", "volume", "class") #Bid
colnames(as)      <-  c("time", "price", "volume", "class") #Ask
colnames(tr)      <-  c("time", "price", "volume", "class") #Trade


#currently i am trying to use this command but it does not work
mymergedata1 <- merge(x = bi, y = as, by = "time", all = TRUE)
mymergedata1 <- merge(x = mymergedata1, y = tr, by = "time", all = TRUE)
```

I expect to have it like this :
https://pastebin.com/pMt49yq4

R i all the time get something like this instead:
Does anyone have any idea of how to do this, if yes, could you help me out please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced answer, due to my mistaking that the time across the three columns are identical...

```
library(plyr); library(dplyr)
Dati <- list(Dati[,1:3], Dati[,5:7], Dati[,9:11])
Dati <- ldply(Dati, function(x){
  names(x)[1] <- "time" 
  return(x)})


library(reshape2)
dm <- melt(Dati)
dm <- dm %>% na.exclude %>% dcast(time ~ variable, mean)
head(dm, 3)

#                  time Price_bid Volume_bid Price_ask Volume_ask Price_trade Volume_trade
# 1 05.07.2019 18:58:46     26.41         15     26.42          2         NaN          NaN
# 2 05.07.2019 18:58:50     26.41         15     26.43         14       26.42            2
# 3 05.07.2019 18:58:54     26.40          2     26.42          2         NaN          NaN
```

Comment: But the time are not the same in all columns and if it works like that then the value  goes to the wrong time and all is mixed up, but thanks for helping, is there any other way?

Comment: Haha~! Just realised that the Time_trade (for second row and beyond) is different from Time_bid and Time_ask.

Comment: Thanks, it sort of works, but the data is showed like this https://imgur.com/a/pGiyisx it is not exactly what i expected to see but it is better than my attempt.  It would be perfect if the values of bid, ask and trade with the same data could be shown in 1 row, is it even possible to do such a thing?

Comment: One row or one column? Also, something went wrong with your `dcast` in the image uploaded.

Comment: What is wrong with the `dcast`? But I have to compare if the bid, ask and trade times are equal, if they are I have to display data values in 1 row under the date they share as seen here (https://imgur.com/a/SysT9ca); however, if the data is not equal display the data under the right column for the right date and leave NA or 0 for the rest, I tried to create an image that helps to explain (https://imgur.com/a/SysT9ca).  Thanks in advance, I have complacently ran out of ideas how to solve it.

Comment: This is y console output, perhaps it helps 
"Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped 
> dm <- dm %>% na.exclude %>% dcast(time ~ variable, mean)
Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors"

Comment: Here's what I got with the script above: https://imgur.com/a/XpXtc9X

Can you check your data structure and do a bit of familiarisation with reshape2 `melt` and `dcast`?

Comment: I will check  the data structure and will try to better understand reshape2 `melt` and `dcast`, thanks.

Comment: Hi, i managed to solve it but when i try to use a bigger data sample it just breaks and does not work, any ideas why? Here is a link for the bigger data sample : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WHvs_FWPBEA3E3Urps6YWsXcQ-fxN4iW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'd use the same code and gotten a data.frame with dimensions 20759 x 7. No issue there. Just make sure your intermediate data after `dm <- melt(Dati)` only contain 3 columns, "time", "variable", "value". If there are more columns, it is likely that your original data-set may have non-numeric data-structure for columns other than time.

Comment: Hmm, that is strange, because I can not make it work, after `dm < - melt(Dati)` I all the time have 5 columns ( I will try to remove the non numeric values and make it work) this is my output after the melt(Dati) [link_to_my_output_picture](https://imgur.com/a/EzQtyHt). Sorry for asking that many questions.

Comment: See if this will help you: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1T7He2cEKnvUoNWPPohDV5Yq7CN4nzME8

Comment: Yes, it worked, thanks a lot! But how? Did you do something to the data set or just turned the .txt to .csv and then imported it in?

Comment: It worked but not fully, because it merges the data that are the same; for example, if I have 3 times with the same values in price and volume  the end output will have only 1 time with value of the data not 3, do you know how to fix it? It can be seen in in the data sample too. Time_trade row 2:4 has the same time and price_trade and there are other values too.

Comment: I had an idea to add like n=n+0.000000000000001 0.00000000000000n to the time so it becomes unique value if it repeats itself, do you think it would work?

Comment: Don't quite understand your issue without an illustration.

Comment: It is alright, I managed to solve it, thanks a lot for your help.